# KeyError when saving workbook

Tags: python, excel, pycharm, save, openpyxl

The file transactions.xlsx is not updated and this is precisely due to add_chart(). If I comment out add_chart all these errors does not arise but I want to draw chart and this is the only method I know. transanctions2.xlsx file is created but it is corrupted whereas bunch of errors do come up.

```
from openpyxl.chart import BarChart, Reference

wb1 = xl.load_workbook('transactions.xlsx')
sheet = wb1['Sheet1']
cell = sheet.cell(1, 1)

for row in range(2, sheet.max_row + 1):
    cell = sheet.cell(row, 3)
    corrected_price = cell.value * 0.9
    corrected_price_cell = sheet.cell(row, 4)
    corrected_price_cell.value = corrected_price

values = Reference(sheet,
                   min_row=2,
                   max_row=sheet.max_row,
                   min_col=4,
                   max_col=4)
chart = BarChart()
chart.add_data(values)
sheet.add_chart(chart, 'f2')

wb1.save('transactions2.xlsx')
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Saman/PycharmProjects/Excel/excel_edit.py", line 23, in <module>
    wb1.save('transactions2.xlsx')
  File "C:\Users\Saman\PycharmProjects\Excel\venv\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\workbook\workbook.py", line 397, in save
    save_workbook(self, filename)
  File "C:\Users\Saman\PycharmProjects\Excel\venv\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\excel.py", line 294, in save_workbook
    writer.save()
  File "C:\Users\Saman\PycharmProjects\Excel\venv\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\excel.py", line 276, in save
    self.write_data()
  File "C:\Users\Saman\PycharmProjects\Excel\venv\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\excel.py", line 76, in write_data
    self._write_worksheets()
  File "C:\Users\Saman\PycharmProjects\Excel\venv\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\excel.py", line 219, in _write_worksheets
    self._write_drawing(ws._drawing)
  File "C:\Users\Saman\PycharmProjects\Excel\venv\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\excel.py", line 142, in _write_drawing
    self._archive.writestr(drawing.path[1:], tostring(drawing._write()))
  File "C:\Users\Saman\PycharmProjects\Excel\venv\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\drawing\spreadsheet_drawing.py", line 283, in _write
    anchor = _check_anchor(obj)
  File "C:\Users\Saman\PycharmProjects\Excel\venv\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\drawing\spreadsheet_drawing.py", line 224, in _check_anchor
    row, col = coordinate_to_tuple(anchor)
  File "C:\Users\Saman\PycharmProjects\Excel\venv\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\utils\cell.py", line 201, in coordinate_to_tuple
    return int(row), _COL_STRING_CACHE[col]
KeyError: 'f'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The case matters when naming columns - specifically, they are uppercase:

```
sheet.add_chart(chart, 'F2')
```

I changed `f` to `F`.

Comment: a million thanks and prayers to you
You just solved my problem
I had a sleepless night over it
I am learning python and I know how stupid this mistake is.
Apologies to waste your time over such a stupid mistake

Answer (score 0):

Just to add up

Check out their [docs](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/charts/bar.html)

You should use uppercase

```
sheet.add_chart(chart, 'F2')
```